# Pwa serviceworker corss domain

Tags: cross-domain

I have a web app https://news.awesomes.cn，the host is `https://news.awesomes.cn`，but the js and css files is host on `https://ofm2qnhj5.qnssl.com` , so when I use pwa, the serviceworker cause the corss domain error.

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

No way other than to copy the css and the scrpts locally where your domain is running.